# How to change large count of .pdf to .PDF files in AIX terminal

Tags: ksh, aix, file-rename

I have a bunch of file with the extension '.pdf' but for further processing, I need them to be in '.PDF'

The method I am using is copying all the file to a notepad and them putting 'mv' in front of it and then renaming them to their new format (that is '.PDF')

But this is taking too much time on my AIX server even if I execute it as a script on nohup. As the count of the PDFs is large (≈ 1000000), so I am looking for a way that takes less time.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A machine can't be both `linux` **and** `AIX`. Which is it? And what shell are you using?

Comment: What's taking too long? The runtime of the script (since you mention nohup), or the time it takes you to manually write large amounts of mv commands? In the latter case, you might use shell expansion (which shell do you use? Do you have bash?) to rename automatically.

Comment: I am AIX server and korn shell @tink

Comment: @senatoresconscripti The time I am talking about is the runtime in nohup

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple shell loop:

```sh
for file in *.pdf
do
  mv -- "$file" "${file%.pdf}.PDF"
done
```

This loops over every filename that ends in ".pdf" and calls `mv` using [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for the new filename to remove the trailing ".pdf" and re-add a ".PDF" at the end.

Comment: For 100.000 files the argument list can get too long.

Comment: @WalterA you might be thinking of situations where a utility is called with a large number of arguments; in those cases, the wildcard is expanded (successfully!) by the shell, but then hits ARG_MAX when calling exec() with those arguments. In my answer, the shell expands the wildcard with its own memory then calls `mv` with a single argument at a time, so it should be successful.